Why is the particular solution of an non-homogeneous differential equation not the full (general) solution?
I have asked myself, "Why does a particular solution of a non-homogeneous differential equation don't represent the full picture of a solution to a differential equation?". To recap my current knowledge and understanding:

A homogeneous differential equation is fully described by its solution.
A non-homogeneous differential equation is fully described by the sum of the homogeneous solution and one (out of many) of its particular solutions.
The homogeneous solution represents the inner system without external forces or sources.
The non-homogeneous solution represents the system under the influence of this (particular) external force or source.

In particular, I don't understand why an equation with a non-homogeneous term, solved by any solution, does not encode the information for all cases of the non-homogeneous term, also where it is zero and thus equal to the homogeneous case.

Please include the titles of ODE books have you read.

I cant see. what you are describing. All these DE are have unique solutions for given initial conditions?"Why does a particular solution of a non-homogeneous differential equation don't represent the full picture of a solution to a differential equation?" since most of the time you can not evaluate for given initial conditions,

I'm not talking about any conditions. I am seeking clarity on why a particular solution don't count as full / general solution to a non-homogeneous differential equation (d.e.). Maybe I can make it clearer with an explicit example. $y''(x) = x$ is a non-homogeneous d.e. Here the LHS represents the inner system's behaviour and RHS the external influence. $y_p(x)=\frac 1 6 x^3$ is the particular solution. $y_h(x)=Ax+b$ is the homogeneous solution. Why can't I just say the solution describing all cases of $y''=x$ are described by $y_p(x)=\frac 1 6 x^3$? Why do I have to say $y=y_h+y_p$?

$y_p$ does not tell you that, for example, $\frac16 x^3+x-9$ is a solution, too. There is no general principle to find the other solutions from just one particular one without involving the differential equation again. Namely, the homogeneos equation is what carries exactly the misding information: How to get all possible solutions from just one.

Thank you @Tzimmo, this helped me in a straight forward manner.

Your question refers to the so-called "superposition principle", stating that the non-homogeneous problem $Lu = f$, where $L$ is a differential operator, is solved by the superposition of the (general) homogeneous solution $u_h$ and a particular non-homogeneous solution $u_p$, i.e $u = u_h + u_p$ with $Lu_h = 0$ and $Lu_p = f$, as you recalled.
However, it has to be highlighted that this principle is valid only when the operator $L$ is linear. Actually, this principle is not specific to differential equations, but it turns out to be a result from linear algebra. Indeed, since $L$ is a linear operator acting on an infinite-dimensional vector space of functions, it implies that the homogeneous solutions $u_h$ belong to the kernel of $L$. Yet, the kernel of a linear operator is always a vector subspace, whose dimension is equal to order of the differential equation. In consequence, you need as many solutions as the said dimension of kernel in order to describe it completely by constructing a basis.

After having to refresh what's a kernel again I seem to kind of get what that answer is leading to. But please allow me to ask (due to bad understanding of the kernel),  why does $u_h$ belong to the kernel? Additionally I can't exactly follow the consequence. Would you elaborate this further please?

$u_h$ belong to the kernel since it is a solution resulting in $0$ for the linear operator $L$ right?

@lmixa   Exactly, the kernel contains the elements sent to $0$ by $L$. It forms a vector space. Say its dimension is $n$, then you need exactly $n$ solutions to describe it correctly (i.e. to construct a valid basis).

How to determine the dimension of the kernel? Could we do an explicit example? Maybe with the given example $y''(x)=x$. What would be the kernel here?

So the kernel is $y(x)=Ax+B$ Thus the dimension is $n=1$, correct? Does that mean there is only one solution? Seems incorrect. Probably a reasoning error of mine.

@lmixa  The dimension $n$ is equal to the order of the differential equation, which itself coincides with the number of contants of integration $-$ as a consequence of Picard-Lindelöf theorem, if I remember well. In the case of the second-order
equation $y''(x) = x$, one has $n = 2$, with $$\ker\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \operatorname{span}(x,1) = {Ax+B ;|; A,B \in \Bbb{R}}$$ indeed.

Thank you @Abezhiko
